# ROS2 slam toolbox localization mode config example

Tags: ros, ros2, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not find an example .yaml config file on how to run slam toolbox in localization mode with a pre-generated map.

I tried a lot of different ways. I ended up with the following file:

```
# ROS Parameters
odom_frame: odom
map_frame: map
base_frame: base_footprint
scan_topic: /scan
mode: localization #mapping 

# if you'd like to start localizing on bringup in a map and pose
map_file_name: map_1589815244.yaml
#map_start_pose: [5.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

I put the .yaml and the .pgm file in a folder named *maps* inside my slam toolbox package. I also added this folder as install directory in my CMakeLists.txt

Nevertheless, if I am starting Slam Toolbox with this configuration, it creates a new map instead of loading the "old" map.

I am using ROS2 Eloquent in Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352729/ros2-slam-toolbox-localization-mode-config-example/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2020-05-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those aren't valid serialized maps. A valid serialized map files will be `.posegraph` and `.data`. This localization mode is exclusive to maps that have been serialized to retain the entire state of the slam session (data, graph constraints, laser properties, etc).

Your issue appears to be try to load a yaml file of a map saved through a map server. This isn't a localization mode built to operate on map *images*, rather than map sesssions themselves. Please review this [ROSCon talk](https://vimeo.com/378682207) where I try to make it very clear that a map is not an image, its a globally consistent representation of the environment and we work with that data for our method.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [root-robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/73210/root-robot/) on 2021-09-13**:
Just to add on, after getting `.posegraph` and `.data`. Rename them to test.posegraph and test.data and then in the `map_file_name` add the file to just 'test'. eg. /path/file/test